# Bash command refuses to run in background with &

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I can normally run commands in the background using the `command &` technique.  However, I cannot run commands involving a music player as background commands.

I have tried two music players so far, pogo and then vlc player.  For each I am only manually typing in the first command, but the second command is run automatically from the first causing it to take up the foreground again.

```sh
$ pogo ~/Downloads/cheering.wav & 
[2] 18841

$ Checking local path /usr/bin/pogo
Checking global path /usr/share/pogo/pogo
Using pogo version at /usr/share/pogo/pogo
DEBUG    stdout logging level: 10
INFO     Writing log to file "/home/mcgoy/.config/pogo/Logs/log"
INFO     System info: machine: x86_64, platform: Linux-4.15.0-65-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic, processor: x86_64, python_version: 3.6.8, release: 4.15.0-65-generic, system: Linux, GTK: (3, 22, 30), Glib: (2, 56, 1), PyGObject: (3, 26, 1), GST: GStreamer 1.14.5, Mutagen: (1, 38), PIL: 1.1.7
INFO     Started
```

The bash command is now paused on the task which was supposed to be a background task.  It remains in the foreground until I close the player window.

The same thing happens with VLC player

```sh
$ cvlc ~/Downloads/cheering.wav &
[4] 17686
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)

$ [000056235c753f00] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
 #cursor hangs here
```

Comment: you are fooling yourself: the command is correctly in background BUT the standard output remains your console. Thus you keep seeing messages, but the run in background

Comment: just hit the enter/return key, and the command prompt will be there.  Frequently people will redirect output to a file as well (`pogo myfile.wav >pogo.out.txt &`)

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for https://superuser.com or maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com   , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: ok, I guess the background commands I usually run don't have so much output on start up.  Probably why I never noticed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your output to not be present in the shell.

You can pipe your output to `/dev/null` if you want to avoid seeing anything, or to any arbitrary file `./my_log_file.txt` if you'd rather save the output for later

```sh
pogo ~/Downloads/cheering.wav >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  Also I had to add 2>&1 to eliminate all the output.